# What's the difference between PeftModel.from_pretrained & get_peft_model in initiating a peft model?

Tags: nlp, large-language-model, fine-tuning, peft

In the examples from PEFT source code, I found two ways to load the model:

```
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, peft_model_id, device_map="auto", max_memory=max_memory)
```

```
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)
```

Is there any difference between them?

Im expecting someone gonna help me to understand this

Answer (score 0):

well, with `from_pretrained`, the adapter of the peft model will be frozen by default. U can change it by tuning the configuration `is_trainable`. However, in `get_peft_model`, the parameters are not frozen, u will get a trainable model for SFT.

Besides, you can fine-tune a fine-tuned peft model by using `from_pretrained` and set `is_trainable = True`.